# Why does switching to a different view revert changes in another view?

Tags: java, android, gridview, view

I have three views that can be swiped between horizontally. On a long-click, the color scheme of all three views should change to black and white. However, when I swipe from my last page to my first page and back again, the changes from the long-click are reverted. Why does this happen? I have a lot of code for the three views, so if you think any is needed, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are saying they are in a viewPager?  The viewPager by default retains 3 views, the current view and 1 on either side.  If a view moves beyond this it is destroyed and recreated as it approaches

Comment: I'm using gridViewPager in Android Wear but assuming it runs into the same problem, is there a way around it?

Comment: yes I posted an answer for just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have 3 views, you can safely call this:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

The pager will therefore maintain the views (not destroy and re-create them) when swiped from the first to last and back again.

Answer (score 0):

Your slide (page) root view should have an id, then android will save the view and will be able to re-create it later. For example here:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
              android:padding="16dp"
              android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
</ScrollView>
```

`android:id="@+id/content"` is important.